# Airflow does not run dags

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Context: I successfully installed Airflow on EC2, changed things like **executor** to *LocalExecutor*; **sql_alchemy_conn** to *postgresql+psycopg2://postgres@localhost:5432/airflow*; **max_threads** to *10*.

My problem is when I create a dag which I indicate to be run everyday everything is fine, but when I create a dag to be run like at 10am on Monday and Wednesday Airflow doesn't does not run it. Does anybody know what could I do wrong and should I do in order to fix this issue?

Dag for script which runs fine and properly:

```
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import timedelta
args = {
    'owner': 'arseniyy123',
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1),
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['exam@exam.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
    }
dag = DAG(
    'daily_script',
    default_args=args,
    description = 'daily_script',
    schedule_interval = "0 10 * * *",
)

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='daily',
    bash_command='cd /root/ && python3 DAILY_WORK.py',
    dag=dag)

t1
```

Dag for script which should run on Monday and Wednesday, but it does not run at all:

```
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import timedelta
args = {
    'owner': 'arseniyy123',
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1),
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['exam@exam.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
    }
dag = DAG(
    'monday_wednesday',
    default_args=args,
    description = 'monday_wednesday',
    schedule_interval = "0 10 * * 1,3",
)

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='monday_wednesday',
    bash_command='cd /root/ && python3 not_daily_work.py',
    dag=dag)
t1
```

I also have some problems with **scheduler**, it uses to die after being working more than 10 hours, anybody know why does it happen?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try changing the `start_date` to a static datetime e.g. `datetime.date(2020, 3, 20)` instead of using `airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1)`

Maybe read through [the scheduling examples here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/scheduler.html), to understand why your code didn't work. From that documentation:

> **Let’s Repeat That** The scheduler runs your job one `schedule_interval` AFTER the start date, at the END of the period